# MySQL Server Installing Taking too long

Tags: php, mysql, vps

I am trying to install MySQL server to my VPS. The problem is that when it starts to install it it gets "stuck" on thing called "Starting server" it even gives me popups of:

> this is taking longer than expected, do you want to continue?

How can I make it move forward from this stage without getting it stuck at it?

Comment: Please create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem so others can best assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild that server and use an auto-installer, plenty of panels contain such kind of installer, some of them are free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows you can try to follow this troubleshooting guide https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-troubleshooting.html